# Default language not working in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, default

I have such problem:

- I have localized my app for two languages - English and Polish, with English being set as the Base one.
- I set developmentRegion to "en" (also tried "English") in both info.plist and project.pbxproj files.
- My translated texts are contained within localized Main.strings and Localizable.strings files.

So everything should be fine, yet when I set any language other than Polish or English the app does not fall back to the Base (English) one, instead stays on the last used, supported language. (i.e. Polish if I recently changed from Polish to lets say French).

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I see now. I thought that whatever unsupported language I would set in system settings, my app would always revert to English (Base).

That's not true.

When selected language is not supported then the app is taking the language that is the highest on "Preferred languages" list in system settings. Only if none of these preferred languages is supported, then the base one is selected.

Comment: Its look correct, is there any documentation from Apple related to this?